# Inline js inside a form

Tags: forms

I'm trying to attach inline js inside a form, but it's not working out. Is there anything wrong with below code

```
$form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'data' => 'jQuery(function() { console.log("test"); });',
    'type' => 'inline',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use method for adding settings. I believe this is the correct way as stated on the docs:

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  'jQuery(function() { console.log("test"); });' => array(
    'type' => 'inline',
  ),
);
```

Docs: [`#attached`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached)